# Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3

Tags: android, android-sdk, gradle, sdk

При сборке проекта выдает ошибку:

> File /home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in
>   /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/licenses Warning: License for package
>   Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not accepted.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>   >      build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing
>   >     components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.   Alternatively, to
>   >     transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>   >      Using Android SDK: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 46s
>
> export TERM="dumb" if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew
>   dependencies;else gradle dependencies;fi  returned exit code 1
>
> Action failed: gradle dependencies

build.gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.my"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 125
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
//            debuggable true
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }              
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Google modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // Google sign-in
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    // 3rd-party modules
    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.1@aar'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.2'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'me.philio:pinentryview:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.10'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.0.5'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

    // Async helpers
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'

    // Database
    api 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'

    // Modules for testing and mock ups
    implementation 'org.fluttercode.datafactory:datafactory:0.8'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Испробовал чистку, ребилд, выходил с проекта и снова входил. Чистил кэш.

С консоли вызывал `sdkmanager` и подтверждал что принимаю лицензии.
`sdkmanager` находится на месте как и положено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалял `Java` и `JDK` и переустанавливал заново в корень диска `C:`.
Прописан `path` вроде как норм:

path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
```

JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
```

Файлы с лицензиями пробовал пихать по разным папкам, сейчас лежат здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня Win7 64-разрядная.
AndroidStudio 3.1.2

АПК дебаг-версии создается и на мобильном норм запускается, но ошибка уже как месяц не дает покоя - вот руки дошли чтобы помощи спросить.

Не могу понять что именно упускаю.

**UPD:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сборку из командной строки что ли запускаете? И при чём тут Убунта и 32-битная java, если у Вас  Win7 64-разрядная? На вкладке `SDK Tools` поставьте галку на `show package details` и установите/переустановите `Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3`. Или удалите эту запись из гредла - если Вам не принципиально этой версией нужно собирать проект.

Comment: По поводу Убунты, меня тоже насторожила запись по поводу linux, но найти откуда лезет я не смог, может где то прописано, но я не пойму где.Проект мне достался от другого разработчика и не исключено что он работал из под Убунту.

Comment: Добавил принтскин развернутого SDK Tools. Это оно?

Comment: Такую ошибку получаю с circleci.com, который  используется на bitbucket куда залиты репозитории проекта.

Comment: @woesss Вы можете подсказать где может быть прописано что поиск идет по пути к Убунте?

Comment: Так тогда Ваша локальная машина здесь не при чём. Сборка проваливается на сервере и принятые лицензии из своей папки SDK нужно залить туда. Я с букетом и circleci не работал - как и что конкретно там надо сделать не скажу. Задайте вопрос по этой теме, а всё, что Вы привели в этом вопросе к делу не относится.

Comment: У меня есть другой проект который отлично собирается без ошибки. С теми же SDK/

Comment: @woesss Я вспоминаю что то же самое получал в консоли недели 2 назад. Но с консолью работать не так удобно. Потому на  bitbucket и circleci грешить не могу.

Comment: Все же задал вопрос отдельно по CircleСi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как исправилось:

1) Удалил `Android SDK Build-Tools` все кроме `27.0.3`
2) Провел исправления в файле `circle.yml`. Его нашел в папке андроид-проекта.

Править можно либо с папки на диске либо сразу в **AndroidStudio**.
В студии найти можно так:

1-й шаг:

[image: 1-й шаг]

2-й шаг:

[image: 2-й шаг]

Вот и `circle.yml`:

[image: вот и он]

Что было в файле:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    # Android SDK Platform 27
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-27" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-27"; fi
    # Android SDK Build-tools, revision 27.0.2
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.2" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-27.0.2"; fi
    # Android Support Repository, revision 35 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/27.0.2" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"; fi

  cache_directories:
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-27
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.2
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository
```

Исправил все 27.0.**2** на нужную мне версию 27.0.**3**. (изначально то все закрутилось когда обновился до `build-tools-27.0.3`).

Но(!) упорно не хотело работать, оказалось, из-за ошибки в строчке:

```
- if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.3" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-27.10.3"; fi
```

Банально  опечатался 27.**1**0.3, а не 27.0.3.

После этого всего нормально сблдилось!