# В СircleСi ошибка File /home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, windows-7, bitbucket, circleci

Такую ошибку получаю с **CircleCi**, который используется на **bitbucket**  куда залит проект.

> File /home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in
>   /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/licenses Warning: License for package
>   Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not accepted.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences
>   have not been accepted. build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools
>   27.0.3 To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation
>   to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>   Using Android SDK: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 46s
>
> export TERM="dumb" if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew
>   dependencies;else gradle dependencies;fi returned exit code 1
>
> Action failed: gradle dependencies

Почему идет попытка поиска по пути: **/home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg**?

Как такое может быть если у меня **AndroidStudio** стоит на **Windows7 64-битная**!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе подсказки более опытного программиста и дальнейших копаний в интернете составил себе такое понимание ситуации:

**CircleCi** запускает проверку моего андроид-проекта в **Docker** (грубо говоря виртуальная машина на удаленном сервере). А вот там и используется оболочка **Ubuntu**.

Вот отсюда и адрес файла (режущий глаз людям, таким как я, вынужденным сидеть под Windows):

```
/home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg
```

В данном частном случае пути по которым **CircleCi** пытается найти определенные файлы - верные. Точнее, они такие какими их прописали.

Разнообразные настройки можно делать в файле `circle.yml`. Его можно найти в папке Вашего андроид-проекта.

Замечу, что есть у **CircleCi** на этот счет такой [документ](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-images/blob/2dc1affd6ddd108932ebdd6f9e284d165b75805b/android/Dockerfile.m4), который. вероятнее всего, будет полезен если нужно прописывать что-то вручную.

Как оказалось, вот в этих то настройках и была ошибка - лишняя цифра.
Но это тема другого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836789/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not-b).